# Getting coordinates when GPS is fixed - Android

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2, locationmanager

I am trying to learn work with location service on android. I used the easiest code which I found and try learn on it how it works. But the problem is when I want put coordinates to textView.

**Here is Code:**

```
package com.example.bakalarka;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


    public class GPSActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

        private GoogleMap mMap;
        private TextView txtLat;
        private TextView txtLng;
        private TextView category;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_gps);
                category = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.category);
                txtLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
                txtLng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
                category.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("kategorie"));
                setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setUpMapIfNeeded();
        }

        private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
            // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
            if (mMap == null) {
                // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
                mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
                // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
                if (mMap != null) {
                    setUpMap();
                }
            }
        }

        private void setUpMap() { 


            // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map 
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 

            // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE 
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
                buildAlertMessageNoGps();
            }

            // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider 
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria(); 

            // Get the name of the best provider 
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); 

            // Get Current Location 
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 

            // set map type 
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); 

            // Get latitude of the current location 
            double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude(); 

            // Get longitude of the current location 
            double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude(); 

            // Create a LatLng object for the current location 
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            String stringDoubleLat = Double.toString(latitude);
            txtLat.setText(stringDoubleLat);
            String stringDoubleLng = Double.toString(longitude);
            txtLng.setText(stringDoubleLng);

            // Show the current location in Google Map 
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 

            // Zoom in the Google Map 
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20)); 

        }

        private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                           startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        } 

    }
```

So problem is when GPS is turned off, the app gives me inaccurate coordinates of course, because I am getting coordinates before GPS find my location.

**It is way how get coordinates after GPS found my location and put the blue point to map?**

**EDIT:**

```
package com.example.locationlistener;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private TextView txtLat;
    private TextView txtLng;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    //private TextView category;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            //category = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.category);
            txtLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
            txtLng = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);
            //category.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("kategorie"));*/

            // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 10, locationListener);


    }
    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            String stringDoubleLat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
            txtLat.setText(stringDoubleLat);
            String stringDoubleLng = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
            txtLng.setText(stringDoubleLng);
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){}

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
      };

      @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() { 


        // Enable MyLocation Layer of Google Map 
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 




        if ( !locationManager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }

        // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider 
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);

        // Get the name of the best provider 
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true); 

        // Get Current Location 
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); 

        // set map type 
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); 

        // Get latitude of the current location 
        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude(); 

        // Get longitude of the current location 
        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude(); 

        // Create a LatLng object for the current location 
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        String stringDoubleLat = Double.toString(latitude);
        txtLat.setText(stringDoubleLat);
        String stringDoubleLng = Double.toString(longitude);
        txtLng.setText(stringDoubleLng);

        // Show the current location in Google Map 
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng)); 

        // Zoom in the Google Map 
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));


    }


    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                       startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                   }
               });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    } 

}
```

So, I implemented Location Listener (I hope I made it good), but it looks that app works. If I understand good, first I am getting lastKnownPosition which is faster than UpdatePosition. And then LocationListener call onLocationChanged method when location was changed. I hope I understand it.

**How is possible that I don't need setUpMapIfNeeded method in onCreate? I thought that onResume works only when app was backgrounded.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an examination of your code, I suggest you two corrections:

1 - Fulfill your `criteria`. You're passing it empty to the `locationManager` instance.
2 - Use the `LocationListener` api to achieve what you want. You can found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) some help.

**EDIT:** remove the call of `setUpMapIfNeeded()` from the `onCreate` method. This is actually being called twice (in onCreate and in onResume()).

Comment: the same like nekoexmachina. Thank you very much. How I wrote above I need tomorrow to understand good and make a little order in my code.

Comment: If you have something more that you do not understand, please edit your question. I'll help you if I can.

Comment: I am very grareful for your help and help of Mikhail Krutov. I edited my answer with one question. I had more questions but I forgot them ;-). I would give you and Mikhail reputation if I could, but I can't for now.

Answer (score 2):

Implement Location Listener with onLocationChanged method at least. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: Thank you very much, I implemented this class and location change works good - only coordinates have sometime little more number, like 16.653453333338. Tomorrow I will try understand that code better. I am very glad for you help, I will write here tomorrow if I have some troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Adding new response to the modified question:

The activity on android has a proper **lyfecycle**. You can check that [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). The onResume is called when the activity come from background, but also when it is being created (after the onCreate call). You can check that on the link I provided.

I've checked your code too, and it seems fine to me. If some unexpected behaviour rise, just ask :)

Comment: Thx a lot for nice picture on the developer.android.com. I started learn Java and android maybe 4 months ago, but I don't have a much time in last two months, so I forgot a lot of things. I should reread basics. I will ask you, if I had some problem. Thx again :-)

Comment: Hi  Ze Luis, I was testing this app with some changes on some devices. And I am getting nullpointerexception in setUpMapIfNeeded on some devices (3 devices from 9 gave me exception). All devices had android 4 and higher. Do you know what could be problem? I don't have line of error but how I said it was in setUpMapIfNeeded. If do you know what is it problem I will create a new thread and I will give you check for a right answer.  Thanks again

Comment: You are testing on real devices or on emulator? To use maps the device must have the google play services. Check that please

Comment: Testing on real devices. My huawei honor 3c works, girlfriend Lenovo works, Sony xperia (idk model) works, Asus zenfone 2 works. Samsung Galaxy Note 2 doesn't work, same as xiaomi mi2s and Sony xperia L. Xiaomi and my honor have the same version of Google play services (so this is not problem).  App works except the most important activity with map

Comment: This is a problem now.  I forgot save that output and I haven't got devices where app doesn't work at home.  I will send output when I get back to Samsung Galaxy Note 2. Thanks a lot for now.

Comment: @Bulva send the output when you have it. I'll be online. :)

Comment: Here is actual code: http://www.codesend.com/view/fdef9443977e38d0ab95c9a39a258643/ and here is logcat output: http://www.codesend.com/view/922dbf308981e67657b2c9cb7cb195e4/ How I said, I will create new thread and delete this comments. In new thread I will check you answer as good. I am very grateful for your help. Let me know when you will know where is it a problem. Then I will create new thread (your answer will be first then)

Comment: Now I looked better to log and it looks that problem is getLastKnowLocation ();

Comment: App repaired :) It was problem with getLastKnownLocation (). THx a lot